# How to speed up recovery partition on S3 with Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am using Spark 3.0 on EMR to write down some data on S3 with a daily partitioning (data goes back to ~5 years), in this way:

```
    writer.option("path", somepath).saveAsTable("my_schema.my_table")
```

Due to the large number of partitions the process is taking very long time just to "recover partitions" as all tasks seem completed before. Is there any way to reduce this intermediate time?

Comment: Sounds like Spark is having to shuffle the data to create the daily partitions. Depending on your use case, it may, or may not, be possible to keep the data in daily partitions from the outset to avoid the shuffle.

Answer (score 0):

In the above code, you haven't mentioned the write mode. Default write mode is `ErrorIfExists`. This could cause an overhead by checking whether it exists while writing.

Also we could use `dynamic partition` which could optimize the huge volume of writes that is discussed here.

Here is a sample snippet

```
# while building the session
sparkSession.conf.set(“spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode”, “dynamic”)
...

...
# while writing
yourDataFrame.write
 .option("path", somepath)
 .partitionBy(“date”)
 .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
 .saveAsTable("my_schema.my_table")
```

If you are writing one time and if it's not a repeated process, the use case may not need `dynamic partition`. Dynamic partition is useful to skip overwriting already written partitions. The operation will be idempotent with performance benefits.